# Robotium : solo.waitForText() and solo.searchText() not asserting Special characters

Tags: android, robotium

I am trying to assert a text "abcd : moved to history". 
So my code goes like this:

assertTrue("Message not shown",solo.searchText("abcd : moved to history"));

I am getting the test script failed at this point, although message "abcd : moved to history" is appearing on the screen.

If code goes like this : assertTrue("Message not shown",solo.searchText("moved to history")); It works!!

So solo.waitForText() and solo.searchText() methods not recognizing special characters in the text like :,? etc.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Which version of Robotium are you using?

Comment: I am using Robotium Version 4.3

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write it this way:

```
assertTrue("Message not shown", solo.searchText(Pattern.quote("abcd : moved to history")));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think it should be written that way?